# How to integrate Crashlytics into an iOS framework target?

Tags: ios, frameworks, crash-reports, crashlytics

I have an iOS framework target, and I need integrate Crash reporting system for it.

So Crashlytics looks good, but

This Xcode project does not have any Mac or iOS targets

So, is there any way to integrate Crashlytics directly into iOS framework?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. If you're planning on distributing this framework to third parties, do not include Fabric or Crashlytics in it.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Sure, our SDK only supports being initialized once. Being initialized in a framework and application would cause a conflict. You and the app developer would have different API keys and there is no way to ask the app developer to give permission to your SDK to share stack traces from their code with your framework.  Including us in your framework will cause issues for your framework and anyone that uses it, so that's why I said don't include us! Totally understand that SDK developers would love to see this supported.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!

Comment: I realize this is months old but I have a similar issue and I'm hoping to find a solution. We developed our own frameworks for different parts of the app. Database, Re-usable UI, and Common utils. Can we use Crashlytics from any of those? How would we go about doing that?

Comment: @Mikey I'm trying to do just what you said: define and start crashlytics in a Shared framework used across the app but I'm having issues on runtime, I have logs that says that crashlytics classes are duplicated .. do you have a working solution ?

Comment: @Mosbah, I did come up with a solution for our project but I'm not sure it meets with yours. In our project we built both the app and the frameworks. In the end I didn't incorporate Fabric into the framework, just in the main app. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47722661/crashlytics-report-from-exception-in-framework for more details.

Comment: Did you find any solution? As I also want the same.

Comment: @MikeBonnell :- From your comment it concludes that SDK should not report crash. How can we approach crash reporting in framework target.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks [Mike Bonnell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3975963/mike-bonnell) for [your comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155649//44197268#comment75341137_44155649), which says:

> Sure, our SDK only supports being initialized once. Being initialized in a framework and application would cause a conflict. You and the app developer would have different API keys and there is no way to ask the app developer to give permission to your SDK to share stack traces from their code with your framework. Including us in your framework will cause issues for your framework and anyone that uses it, so that's why I said don't include us! Totally understand that SDK developers would love to see this supported.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution here that allows your lib users to utilize crashlytics for logging.

Your lib can provide a default log function that calls NSLog or Print or what ever mechanism you want. But also have your library provide a mechanism to override the print method used.

For example, imagine you have a Logger class defined in your library:

```
public class Logger {
  private static var printer: (message: String) -> Void = nil
  public static func setPrinter(newPrinter: (message: String) -> Void) {
    Logger.printer = newPrinter
  }

  debug(format: String, ...) {
      // convert params into a single formatted:String, then ...
      if(Logger.printer != nil) {
          Logger.printer(message: formatted)
      } else {
          print(formatted)
          // or
          NSLog(formatted)
      }
  }
}
```

Now, when people use your library they will get default printing you implement. But, if they have their own logging solution, like crashlytics they can override it like so:

```
// in their App code
Logger.setPrinter((message:String) -> Void {
  CLSNSLog(message)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below steps provided in the link to integrate Crashlytics.

[Fabric Integration](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install)

> The most powerful, yet lightest weight crash reporting solution.
>   Spend less time finding and more time fixing crashes. Named the #1 performance SDK on both iOS and Android, Crashlytics provides deep and actionable insights, even the exact line of code your app crashed on.
>
> While Crashlytics gives you powerful crash reporting, with one additional click you can enable real-time analytics that help you understand what's happening in your app. Fabric's analytics engine provides insights into your core goals, such as growth, retention, and engagement. Finally, analytics you don't need to analyze.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thats manual to integrate Fabric into iOS app with executable target, but in my case, I have framework target, and this way doesn't work