# Firebase crash reporting or different Crashlytics API key to mitigate collision with Crashlytics in App

Tags: android, ios, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

I have a custom iOS framework / Android library for which we would like to get independent crash logs / event logs.  I read that using Crashlytics in the SDK would conflict with the Crashlytics in the app (according to the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155649//44197268#comment75341137_44155649) from [Mike Bonnell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3975963/mike-bonnell)) Can I use Firebase crash reporting or a different Crashlytics API key to mitigate any collisions and have crash logs for both custom libraries/frameworks and app? Or what else would be my options here?

Comment: As he said there is no way to use Crashlytics in the app and framework.

Answer (score 2):

On iOS, you don't have any options.  There can be only one global signal handler for various types of crashes for the entire app.  This means there can be only one crash reporting tool active for each of these types crashes for the app.

On Android, any piece of code can register an [UncaughtExceptionHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) and add that to the chain of handlers for the app's process.  It's a best practice to call through to the prior registered UncaughtExceptionHandler so that you don't disrupt exception handling for any other crash reporting tools.  Bear in mind that your handler will receive crashes for *all* uncaught exceptions in the app (not just those that are caused by your library) which would be unhelpful without some smart filtering.