# Can I add Crashlytics to an iOS Library?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am working in an iOS Library and I want to add `Crashlytics` so I can get notified if the library crashes to any user. I have already integrated the `Crashlytics` and `Fabric` frameworks: I added the .frameworks bundles, then I added the Fabric API Key into the library's info.plist as well as the run script phase into build phases, but when the library crashes inside a running app, nothing happens in the fabric dashboard.

**Is it possible to add Crashlytics to an iOS Library?**

Comment: Is it possible? Probably. Is it a good idea? Probably not. Note that Crashlytics won't log anything that happens while the Xcode debugger is attached.

Comment: It is possible, but its gonna cause many problems if the people who use your library also want to use Fabric which is most likely the case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like the answer is technically "YES", but it would be a bad idea to do so.

[Mike Bonnell's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3975963/mike-bonnell) comments in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44155649/3814799):

Comment 1:

> Mike from Fabric here. If you're planning on distributing this
>   framework to third parties, do not include Fabric or Crashlytics in
>   it.

Comment 2:

> Sure, our SDK only supports being initialized once. Being initialized in a framework and application would cause a conflict. You and the app developer would have different API keys and there is no way to ask the app developer to give permission to your SDK to share stack traces from their code with your framework. Including us in your framework will cause issues for your framework and anyone that uses it, so that's why I said don't include us! Totally understand that SDK developers would love to see this supported.