# Crash reporting for iOS library

Tags: ios, static-libraries, crash-reports

I am developing a static library and I want to know if there is any way that I get crash reports of the crashes inside the my library.

I tried integrating Crashlytics but, as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155649/how-to-integrate-crashlytics-into-an-ios-framework-target) saids, it seems that this feature is not supported by them.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you creating the library for personal use or distribution?

Comment: For distribution