# How to correctly set up Crashlytics in iOS app with own framework in order to get logs and keys from the framework?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, ios-frameworks

I have a Xcode project in which the data layer is separated in a framework in order to be shared between the main iOS app and the Today extensions. 
I have followed the general setup instructions [here](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install) and the instruction for multiple targets [here](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html#multiple-targets). I do get crash reports from both the app and the data framework. However, in the crash report I find only logs (`CLSLog(@"Bla bla")`) and keys (`[CrashlyticsKit setObjectValue:@"value" forKey:@"key"]`) from the main app. Logs and keys from the data framework are not recorded in the crash report even though I have verified code passes through them. As a simple example - user logs in and I set the user identifier from the data framework; then a crash happens in the app and in the crash report there is no user identifier.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155649/how-to-integrate-crashlytics-into-an-ios-framework-target) topic in which the recommendation is to not include Crashlytics in a framework that is intended to be distributed as a third party library. This is not a concern in my case and it also hints at the possibility of including Crashlytics both in the app and framework.

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible at all to get crash reports **with logging and keys** from both the main app and the framework?
2. If yes - what is the correct setup?

Answer (score -1):

Fabric/Firebaser here -

Quoting from [Mike Bonnell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3975963/mike-bonnell):

> Sure, our SDK only supports being initialized once. Being initialized in a framework and application would cause a conflict. You and the app developer would have different API keys and there is no way to ask the app developer to give permission to your SDK to share stack traces from their code with your framework.
>
> Including us in your framework will cause issues for your framework and anyone that uses it, so that's why I said don't include us! Totally understand that SDK developers would love to see this supported.

Comment: Yeah, this is the answer from the question I have linked to. I have explained why it is not answering my question.