# iOS Framework Crash in Crashyltics with strange characters

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, ios-frameworks

There are a number of crashes being reported on Crashlytics (Fabric.io) for my app which is live (in Production). I (and my few of my friends) also use the same app regularly but have never seen any crash.

**In detail-** As per the crashlytics dashboard, the crash is caused in a Framework (also developed by me but cannot add crashytlics there - [reference this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155649/how-to-integrate-crashlytics-into-an-ios-framework-target)) and the logs have below details -

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1a59e2a70 <redacted> + 384
1  (Missing)                      0x0 (Missing)
2  (Missing)                      0x0 (Missing)
3  XtraIntegration                0x1061e609c $s15XtraIntegration18QrUIViewControllerC05fetchC0yyFyAA0A6ResultOyAA0A8CardInfoVAA0A5ErrorOGcfU_ + 1728
4  XtraIntegration                0x106136f7c $s15XtraIntegration0A7SessionC03getA8CardInfo10completionyyAA0A6ResultOyAA0aeF0VAA0A5ErrorOGc_tFyAGySSAKGXEfU_yAGySo12NSDictionaryCAKGcfU_ + 1104
5  XtraIntegration                0x1063438c0 $s15XtraIntegration13ServiceClientC11requestJSON_10completionyAA21URLRequestConvertible_p_yAA0A6ResultOySo12NSDictionaryCAA0A5ErrorOGctFZy10Foundation4DataVSg_So13NSURLResponseCSgs0L0_pSgtcfU_yycfU_ + 1420
6  XtraIntegration                0x1061b6e34 $sIeg_IeyB_TR + 52
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x197f63bb0 <redacted> + 32
8  (Missing)                      0x0 (Missing)
9  (Missing)                      0x4b16b68197f70c00 (Missing)
10 (Missing)                      0x621f120198239000 (Missing)
11 (Missing)                      0x1a4d4a8198233b00 (Missing)
12 (Missing)                      0x2645158198233000 (Missing)
13 (Missing)                      0x0 (Missing)
14 (Missing)                      0x494e46819c353800 (Missing)
15 (Missing)                      0x0 (Missing)
16 libdyld.dylib                  0x1980b2f30 <redacted> + 4
```

Also, whenever I get this crash, I see below in my report -

[image]

The screenshot says, there is a Fatal error while trying to unwrapping a nil value. And I see some strange characters like question marks.

Putting these things together, I assume I am getting an error in my Framework ViewController file (`QRUIViewController` in the logs) but I am not unwrapping any nil value in my whole code in that file.

Can anyone please help me understand what is going on with the app?

**UPDATE**
Similar Crash with below logs observed again

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1af933b00 specialized _fatalErrorMessage(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 296
1  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1af7583e0 _fatalErrorMessage(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 16
2  XtraIntegration                0x1025dbb84 $s15XtraIntegration18QrUIViewControllerC03getA2QR12xtraCardInfo7sessionyAA0aiJ0V_AA0A7SessionCtFyAA0A6ResultOyAA0aI13ImageResponseVAA0A5ErrorOGcfU0_ + 460
3  XtraIntegration                0x10252b97c $s15XtraIntegration0A7SessionC03getA9CardImage9cardToken0G6PngUrl10completionySS_SSyAA0A6ResultOyAA0aeF8ResponseVAA0A5ErrorOGctFyAIy10Foundation4DataVAMGcfU_ + 568
4  XtraIntegration                0x1025fc3c8 $s15XtraIntegration17ServiceClientDataC11requestJSON_10completionyAA21URLRequestConvertible_p_yAA0A6ResultOy10Foundation0E0VAA0A5ErrorOGctFZyAKSg_So13NSURLResponseCSgs0M0_pSgtcfU_yycfU_ + 796
5  XtraIntegration                0x1025aae34 $sIeg_IeyB_TR + 52
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x18171ca38 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x18171d7d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x1816cb008 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1068
9  CoreFoundation                 0x181c7032c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
10 CoreFoundation                 0x181c6b264 __CFRunLoopRun + 1924
11 CoreFoundation                 0x181c6a7c0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
12 GraphicsServices               0x183e6b79c GSEventRunModal + 104
13 UIKitCore                      0x1ae5efc38 UIApplicationMain + 212
14 Xtra                           0x10124a350 main + 69 (AppDelegate.swift:69)
15 libdyld.dylib                  0x18172e8e0 start + 4
```

Comment: You have too much missing info there, there are missing first 3 calls in the stack, you need to find a way to re-simbolicate those calls if not is at least hard to find out the real problem there

Comment: Struggling to find a way how I reproduce this. Can u suggest something? I absolutely have no clue

Comment: anything can happen on those 3 stack calls missing there, is hard to say, we need calls 1 and 2 at least because 0 is from `libswiftCore`

Comment: @ReinierMelian: I added logs from a similar crash. Will this be of any help to move a bit further?

Comment: `XtraIntegration` is your private framework right?

Comment: Yes it is my private framework.

Comment: in your framework check in QrUIViewController, some method called fetchResult? or something like that if exist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199944/discussion-between-lohith-korupolu-and-reinier-melian).

Comment: I started a chat

Comment: Is it possible that you have some dSYMs to upload to the crashlytics dashboard that are missing but marked as "optional?"